# I'm looking for a quick entry TODO application that syncs across an iPhone and my laptop

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

I haven't been able to find the following feature set all in one place:

- *offline* access :: Something which guarantees offline changes aren't lost.
- *quick entry* :: I should be able to activate it with a global hot key and it should provide me a quick entry window, either HUD-like a la [Anxiety](http://anxietyapp.com/) or Menu Bar centric a la [Alarms](http://www.mediaatelier.com/Alarms/)
- *synchronized* :: It should synchronize across my iPhone/iPad/laptop, either via iCal TODOs or whatever.
- *0 wait mobile entry* :: Related: some mobile apps synchronize *before* I can enter in a new item.  This sucks.  I want to be able to add a TODO on the go with no wait (and definitely with no wifi).
- *no overdue, or autoadvancing overdue* :: I don't want to spend any time maintaining my todo list.  If something is overdue, it should autoadvance to my "today" view/inbox or whatever.  I should be able to see at a glance all my tasks (including overdue ones) that I need to do today.
- *due dates optional* :: I shouldn't need to assign something a date.

Bonus points for something that's stored as a simple text file.  I'm open to solutions like [Notesy](http://notesy-app.com/) + [nvALT](http://brettterpstra.com/project/nvalt/) + Dropbox.  That particular combination fails because I use Notesy for other notekeeping, and so I can't satisfy the zero-wait constraint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/) (available for Mac, iPhone and iPad). It's a bit pricey, but does everything you want and a whole lot more. I can personally attest to the quality of these apps — they're fantastic and use all three of them every day.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/) or [Trello](https://trello.com/).

Comment: Neither of those seem to provide a global hotkey.  I'd also like offline access, which Trello doesn't provide.  I didn't list that initially, thanks for the pointers though--

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the built-in [Reminders](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205890) app. If I'm right it should meet all of your needs...

I also recently searched for a TO-DO app and all the time I didn't realize I had one in front of my eyes :D